# Add a column to a stored procedure in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, crystal-reports

We have copied a stored procedure created by another company to use for a report in crystal reports, which then runs from a software. All we need to do is add a column. We added

```
ACO varchar(10) NULL
```

within

```
create table #WorksheetAmounts
```

Then we added the following:

```
insert into #WorksheetAmounts
    (JCCo, Contract, Item, ChangeOrderAmt, ChangeOrderUnits, BillGroup, ACO)

   Select 
      JCOI.JCCo, JCOI.Contract, JCOI.Item, JCOI.ContractAmt, 
      JCOI.ContractUnits, JCOI.BillGroup, JCOI.ACO
   From 
      JCOH
   Join 
      JCOI on JCOH.JCCo = JCOI.JCCo AND JCOH.Job = JCOI.Job AND JCOH.ACO = JCOI.ACO
   where 
      JCOI.JCCo = @JCCo 
      and JCOI.Contract >= @BeginContract
      and JCOI.Contract <= @EndContract 
      and JCOI.ACO = JCOH.ACO 
      --and JCOH.ApprovalDate <= @COThroughDate
   Group by 
      JCOI.JCCo, JCOI.Contract, JCOI.Item, JCOI.ContractAmt, 
      JCOI.ContractUnits, JCOI.ContUnitPrice, JCOI.BillGroup, JCOI.ACO
```

When we use the stored procedure in Crystal Reports (through the database expert) the new `ACO` field is not there. We are clearly missing something, but I am unsure what.

I am new to SQL Server, so this is probably something super simple. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you had created the SQL command once and added the new field later, you will need to "refresh" the command so it can show all the available fields. To do that, just right click on the Database Fields from the Field Exporer and click the Verify Database option. A message will pop up telling you *The database file "FileName" has changed. Proceeding to fix up the report.*

Comment: It was actually an issue on the SQL side. I had forgotten to add the field to the return results portion of the command. Thank you, though!